What is 切り抜きが怖い言い方?
I am not sure what is 切り抜きが怖い言い方. Judging from the use of 経験済み, I think it means if that way of speaking is taken out of context, then it can be easily misinterpreted?


Yes, your understanding is correct. The sentence refers to a phrase that is easily misunderstood if presented in isolation. You can understand it as 切り抜かれたら怖い言い方. Here, (情報の)切り抜き (also known as 切り取り) refers to the unfaithful act of misleading an audience by cherry-picking information.
